# Excel aggregate functions to summarise figures against grouped column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, report

I have a spreadsheet much like the one on this page: [Painless Software Schedules](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000245.html)

[image: Sample Spreadsheet]

I wish to create a summary sheet with the Feature against the totals for that feature of "Orig Est", "Curr Est", "Elapsed" and "Remain".

Is there an appropriate Excel feature to generate this summary? Preferably one that will automatically update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Pivot Table to do that. You can find out how you can make use of Pivot Tables in Excel 2003 [here](http://www.edferrero.com/ExcelTutorials/PivotTableTutorial2003/tabid/89/Default.aspx).

Comment: This is great - it worked, but took some fiddling: I struggled to get the columns "Orig Est", "Curr Est", "Elapsed" and "Remain" along the top. To do this, I used the "Format Report" option and selected one of the formats. This seems to have worked. There's probably a specific setting to achieve what I wanted, but I'm up and running with what I needed, so you get the tick.